# Rect IsEmpty doesn't return true where width or height is zero

Tags: c#, rect

In C# `IsEmpty` (on `System.Windows.Rect`) doesn't return `true` where `Width` or `Height` is zero. In MSDN it is noted but not (clearly) explained:

> Do not use this property to test for zero area; a rectangle with zero area is not necessarily the Empty rectangle. For more information, see the Empty property.

Why isn't IsEmpty implemented as:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    return Width == 0 || Height == 0;
}
```

What is the use case for the current implementation?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx Remark to note there "Do not use this property to test for zero area; a rectangle with zero area is not necessarily the Empty rectangle. For more information, see the Empty property." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.empty(v=vs.110).aspx too should be helptul.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya and? That's **exactly** OP question. Or do you mean what `Empty` remarks is answering on OP question? How does it? `Empty` is a special *constant* values to use in rect mathematics, so that it doesn't affect result of `Union` or `Intersect`. And it has negative infinity as a value of `Width`/`Height`. Pretty valid question as to me, as someone may get confused easily with what *empty* rect is.

Comment: Yes, what is the point of having this Empty rect. If i can't use it anywhere? If it is internal then why isn't it marked internal? What is the usecase? The default is {0,0,0,0} is it usefull for graphics rendering. Vector calculus? And what would be the (performance?) problem to use a width or height == 0 in such a usecase?

Comment: @Chetan on the size note: Because both X and Y are infinite values, processor operations *are severely impaired* by these operations. Comparisons involving these values will not affect application performance. (This states we should *not* use it?) So why is it there?

Comment: The property just doesn't do what you think it does.  It only returns *true* if the value matches Rectangle.Empty.  That requires testing all the fields, X and Y as well, necessary because it is a value type so comparing references cannot work.  Giving a value type a sentinel value tends to be useful, similar to null for a reference type, but is never not confusing.

Answer (score 5):

[`Rect.IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.isempty.aspx) is not a check for an “empty rectangle”, as in it having no area, it is more a check whether this rectangle structure is *the [empty rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.empty.aspx)*. The empty rectangle is basically the default value for the `Rect` struct, with all fields being set to their initial value zero.

So you have to understand `IsEmpty` less about the (mathematical) “rectangle” but more about the highly technical data structure in .NET.

Note that the implementation of `Rect.IsEmpty` matches other rectangles, such as [`Rectangle.IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.isempty.aspx). And finally, the “emptyness” of structures also appears elsewhere in the framework, for example [`Guid.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty.aspx) is the same idea.

Comment: Guid.IsEmpty does not exits.  string has an IsEmpty method. And what is the usecase for this property? The default value is {0,0,0,0} where empty is talking about minus infiity? What is the usecase for this?

Comment: Obviously, not all “empty” in the CLR follow this idea. The word empty is overloaded pretty much here. The use case is simply to have a way of comparing with the “empty” (unset) rectangle.

Comment: More like DependencyObject.UnsetValue but still the usecase?

Comment: Kind of, although `UnsetValue` is explicitly a sentinel value and by its nature a singleton.

Answer (score 5):

There's a convention in the standard library that's (somewhat inconsistently) followed throughout, but that leads to confusion in this case. Several types have the Empty property (or field), where "Empty" denotes some special value that is in some sense default, empty or uninitialized, depending on the type.

Unfortunately, this doesn't always make sense.

Some examples:

- `string.Empty` - the "" string.
- `Point.Empty` - the point (0, 0), although it doesn't really make sense to call a point "empty".
- `Size.Empty` - Width = -infinity, Heigth = -infinity. ... Yeah...
- `Guid.Empty` - 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. I guess this makes sense. Kind of.
- `EventArgs.Empty` - a value to use with events that do not have event data.
- `Unit.Empty` - represents an empty Unit. Does that mean undefined? I don't know.
- `Padding.Empty` - Right = Left = Top = Bottom = 0

An example of an inconsistency:
`TimeSpan.Zero` - There is no Empty field or property. But Zero is probably a better name here anyway.

For the Rect class, [`Rect.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.empty(v=vs.110).aspx) is a

> "special value that represents a rectangle with no position or area
>   [...] which has X and Y property values of PositiveInfinity, and has
>   Width and Height property values of NegativeInfinity."

`Rect.IsEmpty` checks for this special value. Why? Someone thought this was a good idea. Maybe they were wrong.

P.S. It's interesting to note that there are other Rectangle types in the .Net ecosystem that follow this convention but have a different notion of "Empty". E.g., XNA's [`Rectangle.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.empty.aspx) returns a Rectangle with all of its values set to zero (contrast this with the `Rect` class).

Comment: Thanks, I guess 'undefined' would have been more appropiate. and because it is not a class null is not available.

Comment: `undefined` would be semantically wrong since it’s very much *defined*. But yeah, naming things is difficult.

Comment: One nice thing: `Rect.Empty` works as an identity in `Rect.Union()`. This makes computing bounding rects a little cleaner: `Rect b=Rect.Empty; foreach(Rect child in children) b=Rect.Union(b, child);`